# When can I omit a word while using a certain construction with apostrophe?

Tags: apostrophe

Is it grammatically acceptable to omit the term "house" in the following sentences:

"I had to go to my sister's to get my laptop because I had fogotten it there, that's why I took so long to come back home".

"I'm going to John's to visit him because he told me he was sick".

"Yesterday I went to Michael's, but he wasn't home".

Answer (score 3):

It is indeed acceptable to omit "house," "home," "office" or "tipi" in the sentence

*"I had to go to my sister's to get my laptop..."*

Strictly speaking, such a construction is informal, since it requires that the reader *assume* the missing word.

**In formal usage** the omission would usually require that the absent word appear, as an *antecedent*, in a prior statement:

*My house is a small cottage. My sister's is a sprawling ranch.*

While omitting the antecedent word may run afoul of strict formal composition norms, it is perfectly clear in conversation or informal writing.

Comment: How can we call this phenomenon in linguistics? What about ellipsis?

Comment: @PeterFerrer- Some might disagree, but I wouldn't call this *ellipsis.*  For a good quick illustration of what clearly *is* ellipsis, see this [link](http://www.myenglishpages.com/site_php_files/writing-ellipsis.php)

Comment: It is not strictly necessary (in informal writing/speech) for the omitted word to appear in a prior statement when that word refers to the person's place of residence, or can readily be inferred to refer to, say, his office.

Comment: I'm not sure you would use this contraction for anything other than a home. I would never say "I'm going to my sister's..." and mean her office. I would mean her tipi only if she had a tipi as a home